# Minimum and maximum values under conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Let's create some sample data

```
n = 10;
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[], 
RandomInteger[{-1, 2}], RandomInteger[{0, 15000}]}, {i, 1, n}]
```

Now, I want to find the minimum and the maximum value of the last column (#6) only when the fifth one has an integer value 1 or 2, thus excluding the -1 and 0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but work

```
#@Select[data,MemberQ[#,Alternatives@@{1,2}]&][[All,6]]&/@{Max,Min}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I suggest you use a different method.  This code performs the same selection redundantly, once for `Max` and once for `Min`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't quite understand your point. Could you elaborate (explain) it a little bit more?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z My point is that this is not efficiently written.  `Select` is part of the function that is mapped to `{Max,Min}` therefor the selection is run twice.  Worse, the selection function is not focused on the fifth column: it is checking for a `1` or `2` *anywhere* in the sublist.  While for the given example this does not change the result it is hardly correct.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z If it is the use of `Alternatives` that you like consider: `{Min@#, Max@#} & @ Pick[#6, #5, 1 | 2] & @@ (data\[Transpose])`

Answer (score 3):

Slightly faster alternative (about factor of 10 speedup compared to accepted solution):

```
Through[{Max, Min}@Pick[data[[;; , 6]], HeavisideTheta@data[[;; , 5]], 1]]
```

**Edit**

And even a bit better

```
Through[{Max, Min}@Pick[data[[;; , 6]], Positive@data[[;; , 5]]]]
```

which I think is even a bit faster than Mr.Wizard's current method.

Answer (score 3):

Though it isn't the focus of your question there is a much faster way to generate your example data:

```
Join[RandomReal[1, {n, 4}], Transpose[RandomInteger[#, n] & /@ {{-1, 2}, 15000}], 2]
```

For the problem itself I also chose `Pick` but I used `Transpose` and `Positive` instead:

```
{Min@#, Max@#} & @ Pick[#6, Positive @ #5] & @@ (data\[Transpose])
```

This proves to be about twice as fast as sebhofer's code:

```
n = 1*^6;

data = Join[RandomReal[1, {n, 4}], Transpose[RandomInteger[#, n] & /@ {{-1, 2}, 15000}], 2]

{Min@#, Max@#} & @ Pick[#6, Positive @ #5] & @@ (data\[Transpose])         // Timing // First

Through[{Max, Min}@Pick[data[[;; , 6]], HeavisideTheta@data[[;; , 5]], 1]] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.162241
>
> 0.343202
> ```

(Timings performed in version 10.0.)

Comment: The `Pick` method seems the most intuitive. I was about to post my answer but I see that @Mr.Wizard already came up with it (of course).

Comment: Well that was just a matter of time, wasn't it... :)

Comment: I think my new version is even faster though!

Comment: @sebhofer I can confirm that it is faster, and I'm not too surprised.  Nevertheless like using `Transpose` as it lets me address columns with simply `#5` or `#6` which IMO make things much nicer to read.  By the way you already had my vote. :-)

Comment: @sebhofer It seems the transpose is costly because the data is not packed.  `Thread` is actually faster in this case, but it doesn't match `Part`.  With packed data such as `data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1*^6, 6}];` my code is still slightly faster than yours. :^)

Comment: Damn you...  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

MaximalBy, build-in function in v10.0.0.

```
f[list_] := 
  With[{x = list[[5]]}, If[x == 1 || x == 2, list[[6]], -1]];
MaximalBy[data, f]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have v9.0. Thanks BTW.